# How to update table's column value in Redshift based on a join?

Tags: join, sql-update, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

How can I update this table with this value in Redshift:

```
UPDATE t1
SET col1 = 'new_value_here'
FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2
        on t1.col2 = t2.col2

WHERE
t1.country IN ('USA', 'JAPAN')
    AND t1.col1 = 'old_value_here'
    AND t2.col2 IS NULL;
```

I get the error: "Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate;"

Comment: Anyone can help here please?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't allow any OUTER JOINS in a FROM clause of an UPDATE query. You need to use it as a sub-query or re-write your logic.

Here's what i did with your query but with your better understanding of data, you may wish to write it in your way.

```
UPDATE t1
SET col1 = 'new_value_here'
from (select t1.col2 as t1_col2, t2.col2 as t2_col2 
      from t1 left join t2 on t1.col2=t2.col2) t1t2
WHERE t1t2.t1_col2=t1.col2
    and t1t2.t2_col2 is null
    and t1.country IN ('USA', 'JAPAN')
    AND t1.col1 = 'old_value_here';
```